# Как сделать чтобы весь конкретный блок стал серым при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, css3

Есть несколько одинаковых блоков. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку весь конкретный блок, включая саму кнопку, текст и картинку, становился серым?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div class="block">
    <img src="pic1" alt="">
    <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <img src="pic2 alt="">
    <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <img src="pic3" alt="">
    <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Есть идея сделать по размеру блока другой блок с прозрачностью 50% и черным и по нажатию, чтобы он был поверх выбранного блока. Но не знаю как сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам поможет css фильтр - `filter: grayscale(100%);`

```js
document.querySelectorAll("button.button").forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    button.parentNode.classList.toggle('grayscale');
  });
});
```

```css
.block{
  width: 200px;
  height: 175px;
  display: inline-block;
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  transition: 1s;
  color: steelblue;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.grayscale{
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

button {
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/223/200/150" alt="">
    text
    <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/222/200/150" alt="">
    text
    <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/225/200/150" alt=""/>
    text
    <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```